# Opening PowerPoint Presentations (as email attachments)

Tags: gmail, microsoft-powerpoint-2013

I would like to know how to prevent Google from commandeering my PPS/ppt files when I want them to open in PowerPoint.

I have Microsoft PowerPoint set as my default program but can't get them to open directly there. I have to download them first and then open them in PowerPoint.

I have used PowerPoint since it was first developed and for many years could just click on the icon, or drag it to the MS icon and it immediately opened.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Should I assume that you're talking about opening PPS/PPT files from the Gmail web interface, right?

Comment: You are dealing with two seperate issues--the Google viewer and opening files with MS Office.  You can disable the Google viewer.  However, you will still likely need to save the files to your HDD and open it there if you want to open it in Powerpoint.  If you only need to view and not edit, MS used to have a Powerpoint viewer (not aware of current status), that might work directly from the browser (though I haven't tested it).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Chrome:

- go to the URL bar and type chrome://extensions
- Look for Google Docs Viewer. Disable if enabled.
- If no such extension exists, check for
  Docs PDF/PowerPoint Viewer. Disable if enabled.

If you are using Firefox:

- Click the menu button choose Add-ons.
- Click Extensions and check for Google Doc Viewer. Disable if enabled.